# How to serialize 'System.Numerics.Complex' using an XmlSerializer?

Tags: c#, xml, arrays, xml-serialization

This is the XML output I get when a `Complex[]` object is serialized:

```
<MyClass>               
    <Complex />
    <Complex />
    <Complex />
    <Complex />
</MyClass>
```

The [Complex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex.aspx) struct is marked as serializable, and being a struct, it has an implicit parameterless constructor. So why isn't each Complex object serializing its real and imaginary parts ? Does it have to do with the fact that the ['Real'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex.real.aspx) and '[Imaginary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex.imaginary.aspx)' properties of the struct have getters but not setters ?

Thanks.

Comment: I linked to the msdn topic. Please see this in case the above didn't work:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.complex.aspx

Comment: post what is in your Complex struct.

Comment: Hmmm, you're right, I can easily recreate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `XmlSerializer` doesn't serialize properties which don't have a setter (IIRC it only serializers public properties with both public getter and setters). You have a few options:

- Replace the `System.Numerics.Complex` type with a type which you create (and has a "full" property)
- Change the `MyClass` class to handle the serialization (and deserialization) of the complex numbers, via the `IXmlSerializable` interface.

The second option is shown below.

```
public class StackOverflow_10523009
{
    public class MyClass : IXmlSerializable
    {
        public Complex[] ComplexNumbers;

        public XmlSchema GetSchema()
        {
            return null;
        }

        public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader)
        {
            reader.ReadStartElement("MyClass");
            List<Complex> numbers = new List<Complex>();
            while (reader.IsStartElement("Complex"))
            {
                Complex c = new Complex(
                    double.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("Real")),
                    double.Parse(reader.GetAttribute("Imaginary")));
                numbers.Add(c);
                reader.Skip();
            }

            reader.ReadEndElement();
            this.ComplexNumbers = numbers.ToArray();
        }

        public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer)
        {
            foreach (var complex in ComplexNumbers)
            {
                writer.WriteStartElement("Complex");
                writer.WriteStartAttribute("Real"); writer.WriteValue(complex.Real); writer.WriteEndAttribute();
                writer.WriteStartAttribute("Imaginary"); writer.WriteValue(complex.Imaginary); writer.WriteEndAttribute();
                writer.WriteEndElement();
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "MyClass[" + string.Join(",", ComplexNumbers) + "]";
        }
    }
    public static void Test()
    {
        MyClass mc = new MyClass { ComplexNumbers = new Complex[] { new Complex(3, 4), new Complex(0, 1), new Complex(1, 0) } };
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        xs.Serialize(ms, mc);
        Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray()));
        ms.Position = 0;
        MyClass mc2 = (MyClass)xs.Deserialize(ms);
        Console.WriteLine(mc2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the implementation of the serializer you are using to serialize the object.
If you try this, you will get what you are expecting:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap;

public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
        var c = new Complex(1, 2);
        Stream stream = File.Open("data.xml", FileMode.Create);
        SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, c);
        stream.Close();
    }
}
```

Instead, if you use classes in the `System.Xml.Serialization` namespace, you will get something similar to what you posted:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public class Test {
    public static void Main() {
        var c = new Complex(1, 2);
        XmlSerializer s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Complex));
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        s.Serialize(sw, c);
        Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString());
    }
}
```

I think that this is due to the fact that the XmlSerializer will not serialize private members (as are `m_real` and `m_imaginary` in the `Complex` struct).